# How to make HH:MM:SS countdown timer, using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i've tried to make simple countdown timer, but i don't know how to make something when the timer ends and i don't know how to make timer with hours `HH`. I can make only minutes `MM` and second `SS`.
So, i have this `HTML` code:

```
<div class="tadc-time-display">
    <span class="tadc-time-display-hours_minutes">00:00</span>
    <span class="tadc-time-display-seconds">00</span>
</div>
```

The `JS` code i used to have is useless(
You can use `Native JavaScript` or `jQuery`, if you want)

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var start = Date.now(),
        diff,
        minutes,
        seconds;
    function timer() {
        // get the number of seconds that have elapsed since 
        // startTimer() was called
        diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

        // does the same job as parseInt truncates the float
        minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
        seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds; 

        if (diff <= 0) {
            // add one second so that the count down starts at the full duration
            // example 05:00 not 04:59
            start = Date.now() + 1000;
        }
    };
    // we don't want to wait a full second before the timer starts
    timer();
    setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 0.1,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

It should also `start`, `stop` and `reset`, but i dont know how to do it( 
**Thanks a lot!**

Comment: You can start with creating a JS number as the total second. Then combine with `setInterval` for each second, format that second into hour, minutes

Comment: You can use setInterval() in javascript on start and clearInterval() use on stop & reset button but in stop button you can't clear data.

Comment: Could you write some code, please?

Comment: I've added my `js` code

Comment: why not use toLocaleTimeString?

Comment: if you know how - share, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var hours = 0, // obtain these values somewhere else 
  minutes = 1,
  seconds = 20,
  target = new Date(),
  timerDiv = document.getElementById("timer"),
  handler;

function init() { 
 // set the target date time with the counter values
 // counters more then 24h should have a date setup or it wont work
  target.setHours(hours);
  target.setMinutes(minutes);
  target.setSeconds(seconds);
  target.setMilliseconds(0); // make sure that miliseconds is 0
  timerDiv.innerHTML = target.toTimeString().split(" ")[0]; // print the value
}

function updateTimer() {
  var time = target.getTime();
  target.setTime(time - 1000); // subtract 1 second with every thick
  timerDiv.innerHTML = target.toTimeString().split(" ")[0];
  if (
    target.getHours() === 0 &&
    target.getMinutes() === 0 &&
    target.getSeconds() === 0
  ) { // counter should stop
    clearInterval(handler);
  }
}

handler = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);

document.getElementById("stop-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  clearInterval(handler);
});
document.getElementById("start-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  clearInterval(handler);
  handler = setInterval(updateTimer, 1000);
});
document.getElementById("reset-button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  init();
  clearInterval(handler);
});
init();
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
<div>
  <button id="start-button">Start</button>
  <button id="stop-button">Stop</button>
  <button id="reset-button">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Here is working sample with comments.

Comment: Wow! That's amazing! But how to style only seconds or only hours?

Comment: You use different divs for them assign different styles and giving them float:left will stack them in a row. Check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
             try this :
             <html lang="en"><head>

              <style>
                @import "//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bangers";
              body {
                margin: 0;
              }

              .wrap {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;

                background:#111;
              }

              .time-to {
                text-align: center;
                font-family: Bangers;
                color: white;
                font-size: 50px;


              }
              .underline {
                text-decoration: underline;
              }
              .time-to span {
                display: block;
                font-size: 70px;

              }
              </style>
              <script>
                window.console = window.console || function(t) {};
              </script>
              <script>
                if (document.location.search.match(/type=embed/gi)) {
                  window.parent.postMessage("resize", "*");
                }
              </script>
              </head>
              <body translate="no">
              <div class="wrap ng-scope" ng-app="app">
              <div class="time-to">
              prochain event dans :
              <span countdown="" date="november 17, 2019 15:15:50" class="ng-isolate-scope underline"></span>
              <br>
              event : minecraft , ip: 144.76.116.78:40020
              </div>
              </div>

              <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.2/angular.min.js"></script>
              <script id="rendered-js">
                    (function () {
                angular.module('app', []).directive('countdown', [
                'Util',
                '$interval',
                function (Util,
                $interval) {
                  return {
                    restrict: 'A',
                    scope: {
                      date: '@' },

                    link: function (scope,
                    element) {
                      var future;
                      future = new Date(scope.date);
                      $interval(function () {

                        var diff;
                        diff = Math.floor((future.getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000);
                        return element.text(Util.dhms(diff));

                      },
                      1000);
                    } };

                }]).
                factory('Util', [
                function () {
                  return {
                    dhms: function (t) {
                      var days,
                      hours,
                      minutes,
                      seconds;
                      if(t < 0) {
                        t = 0
                      }
                      if(t === 0) {
                        t = 0
                      }
                      days = Math.floor(t / 86400);
                      t -= days * 86400;
                      hours = Math.floor(t / 3600) % 24;
                      t -= hours * 3600;
                      minutes = Math.floor(t / 60) % 60;
                      t -= minutes * 60;
                      seconds = t % 60;
                      if(t < 0) {
                        t = 0
                      }
                      if(t === 0) {
                        t = 0
                      }


                      return [days + 'd',
                      hours + 'h',
                      minutes + 'm',
                      seconds + 's'].join(' ');
                    } };

                }]);


                  }).call(this);


                  </script>


              </body></html>
```

Comment: Did you just copied this code from another resource? Bcz it seems to be that i've seen that before

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)?. Thanks